# wsFederationHttpBinding over net.tcp

Tags: wcf, wif

I have services that use net.tcp bindings (both streaming and buffered endpoints.) I'd like to add WIF federated security to those services, while continuing to use net.tcp bindings. I've tried to create custom bindings, but so far have been unsuccessful. Below is the general architecture that I'm attempting. **I'm looking for the correct binding configuration to make this work.**

- Client - WPF Application
- Relying party - WCF Service with net.tcp endpoints
- STS - WCF Service with http(s) endpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. I've blogged the full solution at http://marshaledthoughts.com/post/TCP-Federation-with-Windows-Identity-Foundation.aspx